# Генерация определенной картинки в зависимости от параметров

Tags: php, изображения

1. Мне нужно, чтобы с помощью PHP
   генерировалась картинка. Но в зависимости
   от того, где она находится, генерировалась
   особенная картинка. Например, по адресу
   forum.blablabla.net/t1/ генерировалась
   картинка с надписью "11111", а по адресу
   forum.blablabla.net/t2/ с надписью "22222".
   Это просто для примера.
2. Мне нужно чтобы сгенерированные
   картинки можно было скачать. Например,
   после перехода по ссылке "скачать", сразу
   открывался диалог загрузки файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю генерировать картинку нужно только первый раз и при этом сохранять ее на диск, а потом уже проверять есть ли созданная такая картинка, если есть то выводим, если нету то генерируем->сохраняем->выводим

Вам собственно что нужно? Конкретно. Код всего? Реализация (часть я ее выше написал)?

Comment: Вы похоже меня не поняли))

Comment: Тогда поясните что бы я мог помочь

Comment: написать, как мне осуществить то, что задано в вопросе. Первый вопрос могу пояснить: каким-то скриптом генерируется картинка, эту картинку вставляют на две разные веб-страницы. Требуется, чтобы на разных беб-страницах картинка была разная.

Comment: Ну я и написал выше как это сделать.

+ к тому что я написал нужен .htaccess если хотите такие адреса для страниц.

В чем сложность то? К адресу страницы добавляется индификатор(в вашем случаи это число). По нему проверяйте какую картинку показывать.

Comment: я несовсем точно объяснил. Адрес картинки не меняется. Картинка меняется в зависимости от того, на каком сайте её вставили. Например, юзербар на форуме, где в одной теме юзербар один, а в другой теме - другой. При этом адрес на сам юзербар не меняется

Comment: в таком случаи думаю поможет $_SERVER

http://www.softtime.ru/info/articlephp.php?id_article=69(в низу смотрите что хранит это массив)

создайте функцию которая будет определять адрес и выводить то что нужно для этого адреса.

Comment: так и отдавайте картинку динамически проверяйте какой url или сегмент url и отдавайте картинку скриптом.

Comment: мне нужно не на своем сайте, а чтобы работало везде

Comment: А как вы собираетесь по разным сайтам определять что выводить?

Comment: Смотрите, что у вас в **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].**  

    switch($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
        case: 'http://site1.ru':
            generateImgWithText('Текст 1');
            break;
        case: 'http://site2.ru':
            generateImgWithText('Текст 2');
            break;
    }

Answer (score 0):

[phpGD](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php)

```
bool imagestring ( resource $image , int $font , int $x , int $y , string $string , int $color )
Рисует текст string на заданных координатах.
```

Comment: Спасибо кеп)). Ты вопрос читал?